# Passing all Parameters from method to a block

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby method and a block configured as below:

```
def control; yield(1,2,3); end
calc = -> (a,b,c) { a + b+ c }
```

Now, I want to pass all the params from the `control` method's yield to `calc` block, like this:

```
control{|a,b,c| calc[a,b,c]}
control{|*args| calc[*args]}  # another succint way to write that.
# => 6
```

Is there a more readable way/syntax to write the same? Probably, like the following:

```
control.passthru(:calc)
control(&:calc) # this won't work I know, but still is more readable to me
control.yield[calc]
calc.call(*control.yielded_params)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why do you think it’s more readable, but here you go:

```
control &calc
#⇒ 6
```

`control(&:calc)` is not working because it calls `Symbol#to_proc` on `:calc` symbol. You are likely want to pass the λ ⇒ pass it directly.